# Any way of accessing results from Parallel tasks as soon as they are done?

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin

Currently, I run multiple tasks in parallel and put the results in a list, from which I use the data.
I want to run all my tasks in parallel but as soon as one of the task is done to directly access the data it's data

Here is my current code:

```
await Task.Run(async () =>
            {
                Parallel.For(0, k, i =>
                {
                    var tt = Sites.oneNews(cat, sites[i]);
                    results.Add(tt.Result);
                });
            });
```

I can't wait for them all to finish because some of them take too long. I need to access the result as soon as it has returned individually

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make `results` a thread-safe producer-consumer collection like [BlockingCollection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.blockingcollection-1). It has `GetConsumingEnumerable` method which returns an IEnumerable which will yield an item as soon as another code part adds it to the collection.

```
var results = new BlockingCollection<Result>();

async Task ProducerAsync()
{
  await Task.Run(() => // I removed the async here as it was not needed
  {
    Parallel.For(0, k, i =>
    {
      var tt = Sites.oneNews(cat, sites[i]);
      results.Add(tt.Result);
    });
  });

  results.CompleteAdding(); // notify any enumerable that no more items will arrive
}

void Consumer()
{
  foreach (var result in results.GetConsumingEnumerable())
  {
    // each result will arrive here as soon as it becomes available
  }
}
```

Or if you want to consume the results in the same method where they are produced (please note that I moved the call to `CompleteAdding` inside `Task.Run`):

```
var results = new BlockingCollection<Result>();

var producerTask = Task.Run(() => // I removed the async here as it was not needed
{
  Parallel.For(0, k, i =>
  {
    var tt = Sites.oneNews(cat, sites[i]);
    results.Add(tt.Result);
  });

  results.CompleteAdding(); // notify any enumerable that no more items will arrive
});

foreach (var result in results.GetConsumingEnumerable())
{
  // each result will arrive here as soon as it becomes available
}

await producerTask;
```

Comment: Do I need to reference the Consumer method anywhere? I implemented this in my code but the code in the Consumer method never executes.

Comment: Yes, you would, because how would the framework know that it should call it. This was more meant as an example for the separate producer and consumer parts. I amended my answer with how it would look if you merge producer and consumer in one method.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you reading that [article](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/processing-tasks-as-they-complete/) - it helped me implement a common logic in one of my projects and is recommended by the dotnet documentation as well (I will also link the C# [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/start-multiple-async-tasks-and-process-them-as-they-complete) that helped me find that resource).

Answer (score 0):

Without exactly knowing in what context you are using this code I can say that you don't need to use the async keyword since the operation you are running is not asynchronous. In any case if you need to handle any collection changed event then you could use an `ObservableCollection` and listen to any `CollectionChanged` event and handle the `tt.Result` being added. But bear in mind that since you are using parallelism that means that since your code is not asynchronous then each loop will supposedly finish at the same moment of time (depending on how intense the operation is). Again I don't know the exact context so I can't say more.

Comment: An ObservableCollection is not thread-safe, so trying to add to it from multiple threads (like done here) will lead to errors.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm misunderstanding, but what's to stop you just calling a method from the parallel for to handle the results as they arrive?  Code as below.  We're already on separate threads, so handling one set of results won't block handling the next set, which is what happens in @ckuri's Consumer for loop, which handles all results on the same thread.  This only matters if handling them is slow of course.

This seems so trivial I'm wondering if I haven't misunderstood the actual problem.

```
await Task.Run(() =>
{
    Parallel.For(0, k, i =>
    {
        var tt = Sites.oneNews(cat, sites[i]);
        var result = tt.Result;
        results.Add(result);
        // Call a method to handle the results as they arise
        HandleResult(result);
    });
});
```

Comment: I tried this first but an exception is raised. Cannot change ObservableCollection during a CollectionChanged event